# Persistent user authentication Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

Hi i'm trying to start working with Firebase and Swift, but i'm having some troubles authenticating users and making it persistent across app restarts.

I'm using Twitter authHelper which when authenticated returns a FAuthData object containing the user's uid and all those things.

The thing is when i (or the system) kill the app all the authentication thing blows away and i need to relogin because i'm not storing the "authData" object.

How should i do it?

Thank you so much

Comment: Firebase automatically persists the authentication token in the user's keychain. If you [monitor the authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication) in your view controller, it should be restored. But without seeing your code, it's impossible to say what's going on. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use RealmSwift is best alternative of NSUserDefaults, Realm work faster than NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using NSUserDefaults. This can be done in the following way (this assumes you are using FIRAuth but Twitter login will give you the same authData):

```
FIRAuth.auth()!.createUserWithEmail(email, password: pwd, completion: { authData, error  in

            if error == nil {
                //enable automatic login for future usage
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData?.uid, forKey: "uid")    
})
```

When the user opens the app the next time, do the following check to see whether or not the user has logged in before:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_UID) != nil {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            [unowned self] in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOGGED_IN, sender: nil)
        }
    }
```